# Subdivision surface modifier missing from modifiers

Tags: modeling

subdivision surface modifier I'm trying to follow the donut tutorial.  I'm in object mode, I've clicked on the object I've gone to the spanner then add modifier and its not there in the list.  I've also tried control 1 and it brings up something else.

[image: image of missing modifier]

Comment: Please add an image of your complete Blender screen into your question. In Blender you can do that from the Window > Save Screenshot menu. Then edit your question and insert the image: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you notice the little arrow under *Solidify*? What else is hidden in the list of modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

It was off screen, I didn't scroll down far enough.